# nginx fails to start at boot, but start well afterward

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, nginx

On Archlinux, I'm running a `nginx` server managed by `systemd`. The `nginx` unit is enabled in `systemd` so it should start at boot.

But after each reboot, it fails to start with the following error:

```
➜  ~ journalctl -f -u nginx
-- Logs begin at Wed 2017-09-20 22:14:25 CEST. --
May 06 12:58:58 vps458278 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 06 13:00:29 vps458278 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 06 13:00:29 vps458278 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
May 06 13:00:29 vps458278 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
May 06 13:00:29 vps458278 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

If I start it manually afterward with `systemctl start nginx`, it starts well without any issue.

Here is my nginx unit file:

```
➜  ~ systemctl cat nginx
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
After=network.target network-online.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
PrivateDevices=yes
SyslogLevel=err

ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g 'pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr;'
ExecReload=/usr/bin/nginx -s reload
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As it fails only at boot, I though one of the required units (network.target, network-online.target, nss-lookup.target) were in error but I don't see any strange stuff in their logs.

Why my nginx doesn't start at boot ? What is the best way to debug this kind of situation ?

Comment: Is there anything in the Nginx error log? Test the configuration using `nginx -t`

Comment: @RichardSmith `nginx -t` is OK, no error. No error neither in `error.log`. But my nginx is used as a reverse proxy. If the target of this reverse proxy is down, can it prevent nginx to start ? Eg: if nginx is a proxy to `localhost:5000`, but there are nothing listening on `localhost:5000` ?